# Visual Studio 2017 Actions

Tags: visual-studio

Решил подтянуть C++ после года изучения Java. Вопрос: есть ли в VS2017 такие же сочетания клавиш для рефакторинга, как, например, в IDEA (типа ctrl+enter, ctrl+b)?

Comment: А для С++ полноценного рефакторинга нигде нет. Даже простого форматирования кода и то нет.

Comment: Using Code::Blocks :) там есть форматирование из коробки, и тормозное автозавершение, но оно работает надо сказать. И самое главное быстрее студии на несколько порядков.

Comment: Для студии есть Reshaper для C++, но оно платное, и не совсем нужное, как по мне. Но есть [триал](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper-cpp/), при удалении вычещается не весь, мне пришлось добивать руками, не возвращает в дефаулт настройки студии.

Comment: Встроенный: [Рефакторинг доступен в контекстном меню быстрых действий. Или можно щелкнуть лампочку в редакторе.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dn958075.aspx), но мало рефакторингов. Либо продвинутый и платный Resharper.